# How to get and show specific values from JSON file with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, flask

I've problem about how to get specific data on JSON file. I'm working with Flask and my intent to is get specific data and show it. For example, get `tag` of `greetings` with their `patterns` and `responses`. At this moment I just can show all information of my `intents.json` but I need specific data.

My file `intents.json`

```
{
    "intents": [{
            "tag": "greetings",
            "patterns": ["hi", "hello","hola","hola!", "hello"],
            "responses": ["Que tal!", "hi there, how can i help you"],
            "context": [""]
        },
        {
            "tag": "goodbye",
            "patterns": ["bye", "Nos vemos!", "see you later"],
            "responses": ["have a nice time, "bye"],
            "context": [""]
        }
     ]
}
```

Function of `app.py` file to show data:

```
@app.route("/showing-data")
def showing_data():
    with open('intents.json', 'r') as myfile:
        data = myfile.read()
    return render_template('showing.html', title="page", jsonfile=json.dumps(data))
```

And finally, `showing.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"></div>


<script>
        const jsonfile = JSON.parse({{jsonfile|tojson}});
        console.log(jsonfile);
        document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonfile, null, 10);
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want to analyse the json in your html page? If so the tags python html are wrong than you should select javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to display the entries that were loaded from a JSON file and allow the user to search for individual entries using the tag.
You don't have to use javascript for this task.
The example below loads the data into a dict. It is then filtered based on the search input. If the query is empty, all records are returned.
For easier searching, all tags are extracted and displayed within a selection list.
All displayed entries are sorted by tag.

```
import json
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
    request
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    q = request.args.get('q')
    with open('intents.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    data = data.get('intents', [])
    tags = [intent['tag'] for intent in data]
    if q:
        data = [intent for intent in data if q in intent['tag']]
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form method="get">
      <label for="q">Search</label>
      <input name="q" id="q" value="{{q}}" list="intent-tags" autocomplete="off"/>
      <datalist id="intent-tags">
        {% for tag in tags | sort -%}
        <option value="{{tag}}" />
        {% endfor -%}
      </datalist>
      <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>

    <dl>
    {% for intent in data | sort(attribute='tag') -%}
    <dt>{{ intent.tag }}</dt>
    <dd>{{ intent.patterns | join(', ') }}</dd>
    <dd>{{ intent.responses | join(', ') }}</dd>
    {% endfor -%}
    </dl>
  </body>
</html>
```